# Azure DevOps Server (on prem) upload Symbols (401) Unauthorized

Tags: azure-devops

I try to upload the **Symbols** (`.pdb`) of my Sources to the Azure DevOps Server (on prem).

Therefore I use the Task `Index sources and publish symbols` in my **Build pipeline**.

[image]

---

Log:

The log of the Task is (`system.debug` = true)

```
##[debug]                Fehler
##[debug]                Die von Ihnen gesuchte Seite ist momentan nicht verfügbar.
##[debug]                
##[debug]                TF400813: Diese Ressource lässt keinen anonymen Zugriff zu. Clientauthentifizierung erforderlich.        
##[debug]                         
##[debug]                        Weitere Informationen zu diesem Fehler
##[debug]                    
##[debug]                    TF400813: Diese Ressource lässt keinen anonymen Zugriff zu. Clientauthentifizierung erforderlich.
##[debug]
##[debug]In D:\agent\_work\_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.16\PublishSymbols.ps1:20 Zeichen:15
##[debug]+ ...    $result = Invoke-WebRequest $serviceDefinitionUri -UseBasicParsing
##[debug]+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc    eption
##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
##[debug]Script stack trace:
##[debug]bei Get-SymbolServiceUri, D:\agent\_work\_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.16\PublishSymbols.ps1: Zeile 20
##[debug]bei <ScriptBlock>, D:\agent\_work\_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.16\PublishSymbols.ps1: Zeile 202
##[debug]bei <ScriptBlock>, <Keine Datei>: Zeile 1
##[debug]bei <ScriptBlock>, <Keine Datei>: Zeile 22
##[debug]bei <ScriptBlock>, <Keine Datei>: Zeile 18
##[debug]bei <ScriptBlock>, <Keine Datei>: Zeile 1
##[debug]Exception:
##[debug]System.Net.WebException: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert.
##[debug]   bei Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
##[debug]   bei Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
##[error]Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
```

---

#### Meta:

```
Artifacts: Activated
Version: 17.153.29207.5 (AzureDevOps2019.Update1)
Proxy: Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps Server doesn't support "Symbol Server in Azure Artifacts". Please check the `SymbolServerType` in the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops#arguments

> Symbols published to the Azure Artifacts symbol server are accessible
> by any user with access to the organization/collection. **Azure DevOps
> Server only supports the "File share" option**.

Comment: Thanks you for that answer!